# Converting Microsoft Word Smart Quotes to Straight Quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a program where the user needs to do a Copy-Paste of some content from Microsoft Word into a HTML editor (Visual Studio 2008).

That content in the HTML is then used in our confirmation emails.

Some of the characters like curly quotes turn into ? on the browser & in our confirmation email.

For the browser... I was able to find how to resolve this issue by using jQuery.

But for the confirmation email I cannot use JavaScript.

I tried this ASP.net / C# code but it hasn't worked for me.

```
if (s.IndexOf('\u201b') > -1) s = s.Replace('\u201b', '\'');  
if (s.IndexOf('\u201c') > -1) s = s.Replace('\u201c', '\"');  
if (s.IndexOf('\u201d') > -1) s = s.Replace('\u201d', '\"');  
if (s.IndexOf('\u201e') > -1) s = s.Replace('\u201e', '\"');
```

I would appreciate any help in resolution.

Thanks.

---

Thank you all for your responses.

I am using the StreamReader to read the HTML file containing the Word characters.

```
string sFileText = "";  

StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(sFilePath);  
sFileText = objReader.ReadToEnd();  
objReader.Close();  

return sFileText;
```

Comment: The code you tried in C# seems (semantically) correct to me.  I don't have Word handy, unfortunately, but when you inspect the string in the debugger, zero-in on the smart quotes.  Expand it and figure out it's index, then compare (ctrl-alt-q) `s[index] == '\u201b'` (or one of the other unicode characters you specified above).  Presumably, you should be able to figure out what you need to do from there.

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832020/how-do-you-deal-with-the-special-characters-that-ms-word-adds alternatively try copying into notepad first then into VS

Comment: Indeed. I followed the question steps on http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=jqURWxIWFUe1gNIFTYeAxA (click 'Run', then click the button. Source with Word quotes is in Default.aspx.cs). Probably the HTML editor is the problem then.

Answer (score 4):

I did this and its work

```
   s = s.Replace('\u201b', '\'')
        .Replace('\u201c', '\"')
        .Replace('\u201d', '\"')
        .Replace('\u201e', '\"');
```

You can use the `s.Contains ('\u201e')`, instead of the `IndexOf`